# Set specific margins in memoir document class

Tags: margins, memoir

I am trying to obtain the same effect as I did with:

```
\newgeometry{top=1.2in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in}
```

in a memoir document class, without using the geometry package.
The best solution I found is:

```
\setulmarginsandblock{1.2in}{1in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

While this works for the top and left margins, the right and bottom ones are too large.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! I disagree with your claims. Memoir settings of page layout givers correct rezult. Tested by: `\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.2in}{1in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your comment and confirmation that `memoir` works. How about changing it into an answer?

Comment: Dear @PeterWilson, done.

Answer (score 2):

Let me convert my comment to answer:

- I disagree with your claims. Memoir settings of page layout givers correct result.
- From your code fragments is hard to see, what you doing and what you try to do with `\newgeometry{top=1.2in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in}`.
- If you like somewhere in document to change page layout, `memoir` offer integrated tools otherwise known from package `changepage` (written by the same author).

A MWE, which demonstrate, that `memoir` page layout settings works as expected:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir} 
\setulmarginsandblock{1.2in}{1in}{*}  % <---
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}    % <---
\checkandfixthelayout                 % <---

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document! 
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt} 
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}} 
%---------------------------------------------------------------% 
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document} 
\lipsum 
\end{document
```

[image]

Of course, `memoir` offer far more reach set of options to design page layout. About them you should consult package documentation: *The Memoir Class*.